# How to get rid of transparent background usign OpenCV 3 and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, image-processing

I'm trying to remove the transparent background (the excess whitespace which is not visible here) from the last image. It looks like this:
[image]

The code which I'm using is as follows:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

##Change directory to desktop
os.chdir("/home/meh/Desktop/")


##Reading the image
img_gray_scale = cv2.imread('img2.jpg',0)
img_colored = cv2.imread('img2.jpg',1)


###CONTOURS FOR IMAGE SEGMENTAITON####
##Gray scale image must be used
ret, thresh =     cv2.threshold(img_gray_scale,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
im2, contours, hierarchy =     cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


####Extracting just the ROI
###First argument img is the source of image
###Second is the countours which should be passed as python list
###Third is index of contours (to draw all contours pass -1)
####remaining are color and thickness
mask2 = cv2.drawContours(thresh, contours, 0, (255,0,0), -1)

masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(img_gray_scale,img_gray_scale, mask = mask2)

b,g,r = cv2.split(img_colored)
rgba = [b,g,r, thresh]
dst = cv2.merge(rgba,4)

cv2.imwrite('phone_original_without_background.png',dst)



dst = cv2.cvtColor(dst,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite('phone_grayscale_without_background.png',dst)
```

My question is, how do I remove the transparent background and just keep the phone's image?

Comment: so you want to crop the image to the size of the phone?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use any hard coded values.

Comment: please read [ask]. You did not mention what is wrong with your solution. do you expect us to run your code and test if it is working or not? why don't you tell us?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it seems to do nothing. Assuming that you want to crop out all the outer color pixels, here's my solution

Get all point of interest:

```
height,width = img_gray_scale.shape

fg = []

for col in range(width):
    for row in range(height):
        if thresh[row][col] < 255:
            fg.append((col,row))
```

Get the minimal rectangle:

```
rotatedRect = cv2.minAreaRect(np.array(fg))
```

Use `warpAffine` to crop out the region of interest:

```
def subimage2(image, rotatedRect):
    center, rotatedRect, angle = rotatedRect
    width,height = int(shape[0]),int(shape[1])

    # convert angle to radian and build affine transformation mat
    theta = angle * np.pi/180
    cosine,sine = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
    mapping = np.array([[cosine, sine, -center[0]+width/2],
                        [-sine, cosine, -center[1]+height/2]])

    # write output
    return cv2.warpAffine(image,mapping,(width,height))

cropped = subimage2(dst,rotatedRect)
```

And here's what we get

[image]